# Why does (unsigned int = -1) show the largest value that it can store?

Tags: c++

I was reading a C++ text and while I was solving some questions, I came across this question :-

> An easy way to know the largest unsigned int on a computer with two's complement is :

```
unsigned int largeui = -1;
```

> Test if it does and explain why?

I tried it out, and the output was :

```
4294967295
```

So, finally my question.
Why is the value that and why does :

```
unsigned int largeui = -1;
```

work?
Please clarify why -1 ?

Comment: Read upon two's complement numbers and it will be obvious

Comment: That is the behaviour specified in the C++ standard.

Comment: Thanks! I got it.
I do apologize for a duplicate question.(Very new to C++, coding.)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: It's got nothing to do with two's compliment. The language is specified to use modular arithmetic for the conversion, regardless of how the negative value is represented.